# Texto não ajusta ao tamanho da WEB

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Preciso de ajuda. estou implementando esse site na versão Mobile, mas não estou conseguindo alinhar o conteudo do site no meio da tela de forma automatica o texto quebra a borda.. quero que ele se alinhe automatico sem quebrar a borda e se centralize pra qualquer tamanho de tela..

ja tentei : padding: 20px;
min-width: 320px;
max-width: 800px;
margin: auto;

```
insira o código aqui
```

```css
header{
  background-color: rgb(179, 151, 151);
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

main {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(109, 98, 98);
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

footer{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Alexandre-Ribeiro">
        <link rel="icon" href="imagens/favicon.png">
        <title>DinizTattoo</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        

    </head>
    <body role="document">      
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DinizTattoo</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Web.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Unidades</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Atendimento</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dúvidas Frequentes</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="logo3.png">
        </header>
        
        <div>
            <main>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxxxxxxxxxssbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbxx</p>

                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>


            </main>
        </div>

        
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Copyright by - DinizTattoo 2021</p>
            <h1><a href="https://www.github.com/alexandreribeiro7" class="fa fa-github-alt"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alexandreribeirro/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexandreribeiror/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
        </footer>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Insira `word-break: break-all;` na classe main para forçar a quebra de linha em frases longas sem espaço.

```css
header{
  background-color: rgb(179, 151, 151);
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

main {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(109, 98, 98);
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
}

footer{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Alexandre-Ribeiro">
        <link rel="icon" href="imagens/favicon.png">
        <title>DinizTattoo</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        

    </head>
    <body role="document">      
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DinizTattoo</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Web.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Unidades</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Atendimento</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dúvidas Frequentes</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="logo3.png">
        </header>
        
        <div>
            <main>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxxxxxxxxxssbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbxx</p>

                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>


            </main>
        </div>

        
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Copyright by - DinizTattoo 2021</p>
            <h1><a href="https://www.github.com/alexandreribeiro7" class="fa fa-github-alt"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alexandreribeirro/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexandreribeiror/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
        </footer>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pq negativam sem nem explicar o motivo? Claramente a resposta está certa para o que foi perguntado... Ajuda em que a comunidade negativar sem nem explicar? Só estimula mais a comunidade a não participar, ao menos expliquem para poder ajustar ou entender...